# How to use both (self , request) parameters in a function

Tags: python, django, api, class

```
class searchbox:
    def search(self , request):
        self.name=[]
        query1 = request.GET['search']
        queryset = F360.objects.all()
        for  items in queryset:
            if query1 == items.id:
                finid =items.f0_id
                if finuid is not None:
                    try:
                        url = "*******"
                        querystring = {********}
                        response = requests.request("GET", url, params=querystring)
                        jData = response.json()
                        name.append(jData["name"])
                    except:
                        return redirect('loggedin')
                else:
                    continue
                context =  {'query1':query1,  "name":self.name}
                return render(request , 'search.html', context)

    def details(self , request):
        name = self.name
        return render(request , "details.html",  "name":name})
```

i am trying to create a django webapp i have defined a class with a method called search to make api calls and search from databases which works perfectly fine the problem is i wanna use the defined variables in another function called details but self and request both have to be the first parameter. how do i work around this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Variables declared in a method are local to the scope of method.

Wiped off when the method completes or returns.

Http is a stateless protocol you cannot maintain the state after response is returned.

But you can store the state using [sessions](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/topics/http/sessions/)

And set and get like dictionary

You can do

```
class searchbox:
    def search(self , request):
        self.name=[]
        query1 = request.GET['search']
        queryset = F360.objects.all()
        for  items in queryset:
            if query1 == items.id:
                finid =items.f0_id
                if finuid is not None:
                    try:
                        url = "*******"
                        querystring = {********}
                        response = requests.request("GET", url, params=querystring)
                        jData = response.json()
                        # setting session data
                        request.session["name"] = jData["name"] #setting session here

                        name.append(jData["name"])
                    except:
                        return redirect('loggedin')
                else:
                    continue
                context =  {'query1':query1,  "name":self.name}
                return render(request , 'search.html', context)

    def details(self , request):
        #access session data
        name = request.session.get("name") 
        return render(request , "details.html",  "name":name})
```

Comment: Hey thanks a lot session worked like a charm. can you please tell is if the data stored in sessions can be dangerous suppose if i make a web app and use sessions is there anyway i could be leaking any sensitive data stored in sessions

Comment: @suyashjoshi sessions are safer because they are stored at server side